# Query parameters in docs not showing for views with filter

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have turned on the auto generating of /docs in django rest and I have turned on `limit` and `offset` in setting. The docs shows that all lsit views accepts those query parameters except for views with that filters the list based on a id, then docs does not show query parameters and only url parameters even though the query parameters still works.

I have validated that the query parameters does still works for the views.
I do the filtering through `get_queryset`

My view class:

```
class DataList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        start   = self.request.query_params.get('start', None)
        end     = self.request.query_params.get('end',   None)
        tail    = self.request.query_params.get('tail',  None)

        if(start != None or end != None):
            if(start == None):
                return Data.objects.filter(id_unit=self.kwargs['id_unit'], inserted__lte = end)
            elif(end == None):
                return Data.objects.filter(id_unit=self.kwargs['id_unit'], inserted__gte = start)
            else:
                return Data.objects.filter(id_unit=self.kwargs['id_unit'], inserted__gte = start, inserted__lte = end)

        return Data.objects.filter(id_unit=self.kwargs['id_unit'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class DataList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = DataSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        start   = self.request.query_params.get('start', None)
        end     = self.request.query_params.get('end',   None)
        tail    = self.request.query_params.get('tail',  None)

        data = Data.objects.filter(id_unit=self.kwargs['id_unit'])

        if start:
            data.filter(inserted__gte = start)
        if end:
            data.filter(inserted__lte = end)

        retutn data
```

Comment: the limit and offset parameters is till not listed.

Comment: Are you accepting that parameters, if yes please refer it